# Hay algun webkit para el input type password?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Necesito ayuda con un input type=password, en el edge me sale el ojito para poder ver que escribo pero en chrome y mozilla no me sale el ojo, y no se si sea algun webkit o tengo que hacer un script para que me cambie el tipo de input.

Comment: Recuerda, agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], si requieres una opinión puedes obtener reputación para poder preguntar en [chat], saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No todos los navegadores incluyen ese webkit, en este caso, puedes implementarlo por ti mismo. Te dejo uno de ejemplo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show_hide_password a").on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#show_hide_password input').attr("type") == "text"){
            $('#show_hide_password input').attr('type', 'password');
            $('#show_hide_password i').addClass( "fa-eye-slash" );
            $('#show_hide_password i').removeClass( "fa-eye" );
        }else if($('#show_hide_password input').attr("type") == "password"){
            $('#show_hide_password input').attr('type', 'text');
            $('#show_hide_password i').removeClass( "fa-eye-slash" );
            $('#show_hide_password i').addClass( "fa-eye" );
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:100px 0;
  background-color:#efefef
}
a, a:hover{
  color:#333
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b9bdbd120a.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
      <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Clave</label>
    <div class="input-group" id="show_hide_password">
      <input class="form-control" type="password">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, entonces tendré que hacer mi propio campo, y gracias también por el ejemplo.